# Parsing XML in R and concatenating results in a string

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I am stuck while performing a very simple parsing of an xml file through R

Here are two observations (15_5/00236_CAMERA, 15_5/00235_CAMERA) of the xml I am interested in parsing:

```
    <p id="15_5/00236_CAMERA"><span class="id">15_5/00236_CAMERA</span><span class="tipologia">INTERROGAZIONE A RISPOSTA IN COMMISSIONE</span><span class="legRomano">XV</span><span class="primoFirmatario">ZUCCHI ANGELO ALBERTO</span><span class="descrittore"><label>SERRE E VIVAI</label><label>CONTRIBUTI PUBBLICI</label><label>FIORI E FLORICOLTURA</label><label>ENERGIA GEOTERMICA</label><label>GRANDINE GELATE E NEVE</label><label>PARTECIPAZIONI STATALI</label></span><span class="ramo">CAMERA</span><span class="dataPresentazione">27/09/2006</span><span class="numero">5/00236</span></p>
<p id="15_5/00235_CAMERA"><span class="id">15_5/00235_CAMERA</span><span class="tipologia">INTERROGAZIONE A RISPOSTA IN COMMISSIONE</span><span class="legRomano">XV</span><span class="primoFirmatario">MARTINELLO LEONARDO</span><span class="descrittore"><label>DENOMINAZIONE DI ORIGINE DI PRODOTTI</label><label>ORTAGGI E VERDURE</label><label>LEGUMI</label></span><span class="ramo">CAMERA</span><span class="dataPresentazione">27/09/2006</span><span class="numero">5/00235</span></p>
```

I want to create a vector, one element for each observation, containing all labels in class "descrittore" concatenated in a string, dividing each label by means of a semicolon

[1] "SERRE E VIVAI;CONTRIBUTI PUBBLICI;FIORI E FLORICOLTURA;ENERGIA GEOTERMICA;GRANDINE GELATE E NEVE;PARTECIPAZIONI STATALI"

[2] "DENOMINAZIONE DI ORIGINE DI PRODOTTI;ORTAGGI E VERDURE;LEGUMI"

**SOLUTION:**

Here is the solution (thanks to Duncan Temple Lang for helping out)

```
library(xml)
MY_PARSED_FILE <- htmlParse(file)
descrittore <- sapply(xpathSApply(MY_PARSED_FILE, "//span[@class='descrittore']", function(node) xmlSApply(node, xmlValue)), function(x) paste(x, sep="", collapse=";"))
```

Comment: "I tried the following:" and what happened?

Comment: you must not have parsed for new line character in your file,if its '\n' then you could  try `unlist(strsplit(descrittore ,'\n'))`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I reformulated my question and now it should be clearer